# Why would there be a POST request with a referer of google.com?

Tags: asp.net, security

I notice that my ASP.NET web app sometimes gets POST requests with the REFERER being a google.com URL.  How is that possible?  Is this some kind of hacking attempt?

Here are some of the more interesting HTTP values (I have replaced my real site with "example.com"):

```
HTTP_REFERER = http://www.google.com/gwt/x/e?wsc=bf&wsi=d9f494c200f04c82&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com&ei=65oLUNikApHoxAKykMHqBA&whp=1view_unadapted%3B2http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mysite.com     
REQUEST_METHOD = POST     
HTTP_COOKIE = ASP.NET_SessionId=eakdubyv3bfj33l0adtyhamc 
HTTP_USER_AGENT = KWC-Buckle/ABO1107 UP.Browser/7.2.7.2.551 (GUI) MMP/2.0     
CONTENT_LENGTH = 195 
CONTENT_TYPE = application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
SCRIPT_NAME = /cgi/webloginscript.aspx 
SERVER_PORT = 443 
SERVER_PORT_SECURE = 1 
HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE = "mms.mycricket.com" 
HTTPS = on
```

**EDIT:** When I tested the Referer URL using "wget", I see that google responds with a 302 redirect to http://www.example.com .  So could it be that the mobile browser is preforming the redirect but not resetting the referer to http://www.example.com as it should?  Then when the user fills in the form and tries to submit it, the referer is still google.com?  Buggy mobile browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the giveaway is the user agent.

someone is clicking on search results from a mobile device and google is rendering a mobile friendly version of your page.

Comment: Simplistically speaking Google is acting as a proxy

Answer (score 0):

Usually a web crawler would register HEAD type http request first.  This looks like a Google redirect link after clicking a search result and no clue why it would be a POST vs. a GET.  I notice the user agent seems to be a mobile browser on Cricket (wireless carrier) so it could be a built-in search and redirect they built into their OS.

Comment: bottom line, doesn't look like hack attempt and likely a custom Google search redirect on mobile device.